# PC shuts off when attempting to wake up

Tags: power-supply, gpu

I just built a PC from scratch, and I have the following problem:

Every time my PC sleeps, when I try to wake it, it shuts off completely and restarts. A noise seems to come from the psu as well.

I've heard that this problem may be due to the way that my pc handles voltage while waking up, rendering the gpu underpowered.

Here are my specifications:

- CPU: Ryzen 9 3900
- GPU: EVGA RTX 2080 super
- PSU: Corsair rm750x
- OS: Windows 10

Does anyone have any idea what this problem may be ?

Answer (score 0):

It has to be the power supply.

If the video card requires 2 power cables, make sure both are connected.

Do you have a lot of HDD's connected? LED's, multiple case fans, liquid cooling, overclock, multiple RAM sticks, multiple USB devices, etc?

This happened to me with a 650W power supply, when I had 6 HDD's connected - also happened on normal boot, first time or even two - PC would just power off after powered down. After I replaced a few HDD's with SSD's and removed a fan, the problem stopped happening.

Comment: I only have one NVMe SSD. I do have liquid cooling, 2 RAM sticks, many USB devices, but I'm not overclocking it. The video card does take two 6+2 pin power cable, but does that mean it needs two cables ? I have one cable which has two heads on one end.

Comment: If the video card has 2 power connector slots, you need to plug in a power cable in each one. Here is an example: https://www.guru3d.com/index.php?ct=articles&action=file&id=43682&admin=0a8fcaad6b03da6a6895d1ada2e171002a287bc1

Comment: So I did that yesterday: connected two dedicated cables to the video card, but the problem still persists. I also called EVGA support and the guy said he's never heard of this problem lol.

Comment: I think maybe the power supply is not providing enough at boot.

Good news is that now that the video card has two connectors you won't run into problems while gaming (PCIE is not able to provide much power, I think around 65W only) and more demanding games might make the card require more power.

Comment: But I have a 750W psu, and Nvidia says the card only needs 650W. Isn’t it enough ? Or is it a problem only while booting from sleep ?

Comment: That is true, but keep in mind that the fans, USB devices and all the other components also use power. Same with RGB if you have it. The fact is your power supply turns off. Unless something is faulty in your PC (PSU, graphics card, PCIE slot, etc) the more likely reason is that the PSU is not able to provide enough power to the GPU (or some other component) at first boot, and as a protective measure not to break something it shuts down.

Comment: That's so weird though, because the PC otherwise works just fine. Turning it on (not from sleep) works fine. Furthermore, I'm able to run extremely demanding games on it, and there's no problem whatsoever. How can it run anything I throw at it but can it not come out of sleep. That's mind boggling. Thanks for the help :)